# In a Plotly Scatter plot , how do you join two set of points with a line?

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
layout1= go.Layout(title=go.layout.Title(text="A graph",x=0.5),
        xaxis={'title':'x[m]'},
        yaxis={'title':'y[m]','range':[-10,10]})

point_plot=[
            go.Scatter(x=[3,4],y=[1,2],name="V0"),
            go.Scatter(x=[1,2],y=[1,1],name="V0"),
            go.Scatter(x=[5,6],y=[2,3],name="GT")
    ]
      
      
      
go.Figure(data=point_plot, layout=layout1).show()
```

which produces the following plot

[image]

However this is not what I want exactly.
What I want is that the two sets marked with "V0" must be of the same color and have only one mark in the legend. (In fact I am going to plot much more than two sets, like 20 sets of pairs joined by a line and they all have to be the same color and have only one mark in the legend)

Comment: if you want to combine two `V0` segments you need plot them together as `go.Scatter(x=[1,2, 3,4],y=[1,1, 1, 2],name="V0")`

Comment: Yes, but if I put them in only one scatter (like the one you provided), it will produce a line (joining four points) and not two sets of two points joint, which is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine two `V0` segments in a single scatter and add an extra point with `np.nan` to split two segments value as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
layout1= go.Layout(title=go.layout.Title(text="A graph",x=0.5),
        xaxis={'title':'x[m]'},
        yaxis={'title':'y[m]','range':[-10,10]})

point_plot=[
            go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,3,4],y=[1,1,np.nan, 1,2],name="V0"),
            go.Scatter(x=[5,6],y=[2,3],name="GT")
    ]
      
      
      
go.Figure(data=point_plot, layout=layout1).show()
```

Answer (score 11):

Here you should use the same `legendgroup` for the first to traces and set the same color manually. To hide the second legend the parameter is `showlegend=False`.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

line_color=dict(color="blue")

layout1= go.Layout(title=go.layout.Title(text="A graph",x=0.5),
        xaxis={'title':'x[m]'},
        yaxis={'title':'y[m]','range':[-10,10]})

point_plot=[
  go.Scatter(x=[3,4],
             y=[1,2],
             name="V0",
             legendgroup="V0",
             line=line_color),
  go.Scatter(x=[1,2],
             y=[1,1],
             name="V0",
             legendgroup="V0",
             line=line_color,
             showlegend=False),
  go.Scatter(x=[5,6],
             y=[2,3],
             name="GT")]
      
      
go.Figure(data=point_plot, layout=layout1).show()
```

[image]